Looking for any details about a skit about the foundation for the the tragically hip?
I am looking for any details about a skit about the Foundation for The Tragically Hip? It might have been SNL, but it might also have been on a VHS released by Playboy.
I partially remember a line similar to "...the cumbersome - Mercedes Benz", as if it were a piece of necessary medical equipment. 
I think of it whenever I read "Affluenza".
Some sources suggest it was part of SNL 6:7 but I did not see it on NBC's site.

Feel free to re-tag

So, you're attempting to identify who actually performed it? In general, we will help figuring out who created a skit but we do not help with sourcing the actual videos. That is off-topic here.

Whatever information I can find out about it might help.

@walt Thanks for the Hulu link. That was captioned "Foundation for The Tragically Hip" but it was actually "Dinner With The Livelys".

Yeah, sorry, I just watched it too. I removed the link.

It's available on both Elephant Parts and season 6 of  SNL.

Elephant Parts is a collection of comedy and music videos made in 1981 by Michael Nesmith, former member of the Monkees. [...] There are various comedy sketches between musical numbers: The most notable sketches are "Elvis Drugs", "Neighborhood Nuclear Superiority", "The Tragically Hip" (which was the inspiration for [the name] of the Canadian band and was featured as a pretaped sketch on a season six episode of Saturday Night Live)

The specific SNL episode is 'Karen Black/Cheap Trick/Stanley Clarke Trio' (season 6, episode 7) which aired on 17 January, 1981.

The host for the episode is Karen Black (her second appearance), and the musical guests are Cheap Trick and The Stanley Clarke Trio. The skits for this episode are as follows: During the Carters' last days in the White House, Rosalyn instructs Jimmy and Amy to take away everything they can carry. A music company pitches an album of classical works that inspired the hit songs of today. A foundation to help the tragically hip solicits donations.


According to http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/dvd-elephant-parts-bill-martin/3626987, it should be at about 7min & 40 seconds into the video but where I found to watch it online jumps at that point to the next skit, "Art by the pound".

@TecBrat Because it's the wrong version. See the first added skit here.
